# What's wrong with my code preg_match?

Tags: php, preg-match

While running this regex:

```
if(!preg_match("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$",  $email)){`
```

I get the following error message:

> Warning: preg_match(): No ending delimiter '^' found in C:\xampp\htdocs\Test\source\index.php on line 28.

Why?

Comment: Alternatively, you can use: `if ( ! filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))` http://php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php

Answer (score 0):

preg_match() thinks you're using the carat "^" as the delimiter. Generally, you'll find most people use "/".

```
if(!preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(.[_a-z0-9-]+)@[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)(.[a-z]{2,3})$/", $email)) {
```